# Avoiding cross referencing in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I have a structure like this:

```
 UIViewController
    SCNView
       SKScene
```

The `ViewController` creates and holds a `SCNView` and the `SCNView` holds a `SKScene` which is showing `GUI` elements. You can click on buttons of the `SKScene` to manipulate the `UIViewController`. The `SKScene` is calling functions of the `UIViewController`.

This is where the cross reference is used, the `SKScene` has a reference to the `UIViewController` and the `UIViewController` is referencing the `SKScene` (through the `SCNView`).

It is often suggested to avoid cross references, but how would I do it in this case?

I can think of passing callbacks or even polling for variable changes but I think that would make the code much less clean.

Comment: Why does the scene need a reference to the view controller?

Comment: You could use delegate pattern, notifications or blocks.

Comment: The scene calls a function of the view controller: [viewController switchToOtherViewController];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"It is often suggested to avoid cross references" - I have never heard that term used in iOS development, so that's news to me. You have to avoid reference cycles, which means you decide who is the owner of everything, and that owner holds strong references to whatever it wants to reference, but anything it references holds only a weak reference back.

Usually you wouldn't hold a reference to a view controller. Instead you define a protocol with exactly the functionality that your SKScene needs to get supplied from someone else, your view controller supports the protocol, and the SKScene gets a delegate supporting that protocol. Much more flexible.

Comment: And much more testable!

Comment: Ok, I will just continue to use weak references, but it feels wrong because the compiler is complaining until I add a "@class" definition.